# URL encoding issue - HttpWebRequest doesn't work, Firefox does

Tags: c#, encoding, web-services, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to call a rest webservice provided by a lims system (basically a chemistry lab database + interface).    It was working great until some > ascii characters showed up (specifically characters with circumflexes, umlauts, etc.)

When calling the webservice passing the value àèïõû I have the following argument:

```
&componentValue=àèïõû
```

HttpWebRequest, without any pre-escaping  OR with Uri.EscapeDataString() called on the value gives:

```
Ã Ã¨Ã¯ÃµÃ»
```

Firefox, with the same website as was passed to HttpWebRequest gives the correct value:

```
àèïõû
```

Now for the escaping itself:
Uri.EscapeDataString() appears to escape "àèïõû"  as:

```
%C3%A0%C3%A8%C3%AF%C3%B5%C3%BB
```

Firefox escapes "àèïõû" as:

```
%E0%E8%EF%F5%FB
```

As the latter works I would of course prefer to use that as my escape method, but I really don't know where to begin.  I've found plenty of information on different methods of handling encodes on the response data, but not on the request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapedatastring.aspx):

> *Uri.EscapeDataString Method*
>
> [...] All Unicode characters are converted to UTF-8 format before being escaped.

So what you're seeing is the UTF-8 encoded version of `àèïõû`.

Unlike [Uri.EscapeDataString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapedatastring.aspx), [HttpUtility.UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h10z5byc.aspx) allows you to specify an encoding explicitly:

```
HttpUtility.UrlEncode("àèïõû", Encoding.GetEncoding("latin1"));
```

Alternatively, you could write your own version; for example:

```
string.Concat(Encoding
   .GetEncoding("latin1")
   .GetBytes("àèïõû")
   .Select(x => "%" + x.ToString("x2"))
   .ToArray());
```

Both result in `"%e0%e8%ef%f5%fb"`.

A better solution would probably be to accept UTF-8 encoded query strings in the webservice.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer and extended information - don't have control of the webservice, but have sent in the information to the vendor.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `Uri.HexEscape()` will do what you want, but only one character at a time.  I'd roll your own escaping function and hope that your codepage is always the same codepage that the webservice is using, since it appears that the webservice doesn't support Unicode.